# Can the PayPal Sandbox "charge" a transaction fee?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to test how my listener file treats PayPal transactions, but the Sandbox does not pass anything about the transaction fee.  I am pretty sure that the live PayPal site does pass the transaction fee to a listener file.

Here is what is posted to the listener file:

```
mc_gross    =>  25.00
protection_eligibility  =>  Ineligible
address_status  =>  confirmed
item_number1    =>  C-1001
tax =>  0.00
item_number2    =>  C-1002
payer_id    =>  XXXXXXXXXXXXX
address_street  =>  1 Main St
payment_date    =>  15:10:14 May 27, 2013 PDT
payment_status  =>  Pending
charset =>  windows-1252
address_zip =>  95131
mc_shipping =>  0.00
mc_handling =>  0.00
first_name  =>  Jon
address_country_code    =>  US
address_name    =>  Jon Doe
notify_version  =>  3.7
custom  =>  *Member ID passed as custom variable*
payer_status    =>  verified
address_country =>  United States
num_cart_items  =>  2
mc_handling1    =>  0.00
mc_handling2    =>  0.00
address_city    =>  San Jose
verify_sign =>  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-999999999999999999999999
payer_email =>  jon@mydomain.com
mc_shipping1    =>  0.00
mc_shipping2    =>  0.00
tax1    =>  0.00
tax2    =>  0.00
txn_id  =>  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
payment_type    =>  instant
last_name   =>  Doe
address_state   =>  CA
item_name1  =>  General Expenses
receiver_email  =>  finance@ourdomain.org
item_name2  =>  Building Fund
quantity1   =>  1
quantity2   =>  1
pending_reason  =>  unilateral
txn_type    =>  cart
mc_gross_1  =>  10.00
mc_currency =>  USD
mc_gross_2  =>  15.00
residence_country   =>  US
test_ipn    =>  1
transaction_subject =>  *Member ID passed as custom variable*
payment_gross   =>  25.00
ipn_track_id    =>  9999999999999
```

Comment: Perhaps the sandbox doesn't pass a fee.  But what have you tried so far? Show us an IPN message printed out as a string or array.

Answer (score 0):

You should see variables for `mc_fee` and `payment_fee`.  If you are not seeing thise variables, can you provide the transaciton id and I can take a look at it on my side.  Also, you can find a list of the IPN/PDT variables listed [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/).

Comment: To be clear, I am referring to the Sandbox, not live PayPal.  I am mainly concerned with my designing my system at this point.  The above transaction was from the Sandbox site.  I just ran another sandbox transaction - id: 4ME46318GF921513F.